# Why is my code giving Runtime Error?

Tags: c++, numbers, primes, prime-factoring

I am trying to make a Amazing Prime Series(APS) in which there is a vector myvector
myvector[0] = myvector[1] = 0

For n > 1, myvector[n] = myvector[n - 1] + f(n), where f(n) is smallest prime factor of n.

INPUT
    3(No. of test cases)

```
2 
3
4
```

OUTPUT

```
2
5
7


#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int p)
{
 int c=sqrt(p);
 if(c==1)
 {
     return true;
 }
 else
 {
     for(int i=2;i<=c;i++)
    {if(p%i==0)
        {return false;}
    else
        {return true;}
  }
 }
}
int func(int n1)
{
    if(n1%2==0)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if(isPrime(n1)==true)
        {
            return n1;
        }
        else
        {
        int c1= sqrt(n1);
            for(int i=2;i<=c1;i++)
            {
                if(n1%i==0 && isPrime(i)==true)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
      }
    }
}
main()
{
    int t;
    std::vector<int> myvector;
    myvector[0]=myvector[1]=0;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        while(n>1)
        {
            myvector[n]=myvector[n-1]+func(n);
            cout<<myvector[n]<<endl;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: _What_ error is your code giving?

Comment: It is giving a runtime error hence not visible in my console screen

Comment: t has no init value and to access a vector through index you need to std::vector<int> myvector (10);   // 10 zero-initialized elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector is empty, any indexing in it will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Either you need to [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) the vector once you know the exact size, or you should [push back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) elements as needed.

---

And the problem with the vector is not the *only* undefined behavior you have. You use the local variable `t` without it being initialized, which means its value will be *indeterminate* and using it in any way besides initializing it will also lead to UB.

Comment: a vector does not need a defined size. I think, you were trying to say: "Your vector is empty".

Comment: I want a dynamic Size..how can I do it ?

Comment: @cdonat  I am filling the values inside the vector..is it necessary to intilize it at the time of declaration and then override the values ?

Answer (score 1):

Fill your vector with `push_back()`:

```
auto main(int, char**) -> int // <- corrected function prototype
{
    // this loop construct is ugly. use a for loop, when that is what you intent.
    // int t = 42; // <- t was not initialized
    // while(t--)
    for(int t = 0; t < 42; t++)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        // we create a new vector in each run through the loop. 
        auto myvector = std::vector<int>{0, 0};
        // your loop did never break, because you changed nothing of
        // the condition inisde.
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            myvector.push_back(myvector.back() + func(i));
            std::cout << myvector.back() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Please also create a new vector inside your loop. Alternatively you could also clear the vector, but that is a bit weaker on stating the intent. If you try to cache values, you have calculated before, don't recalculate them over and over again.

BTW.: You don't need to store all the values of the sequence:

```
auto main(int, char**) -> int
{
    for(int t = 0; t < 42; t++)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        int current = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            current += func(i);
            std::cout << current << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

That is not only shorter, but probably also a lot faster, because the CPU can hold `current` in a register and therefore does not have to load and store relatively slow memory.

Beware: All code is untested and might contain more bugs.